# About $F = K u$

Tags: classical-mechanics, finite-element-method

Let's say we have the stiffness matrix K
$$
  K =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
    k_{11} & k_{12} & k_{13} & k_{14} \\
    k_{21} & k_{22} & k_{23} & k_{24}\\
    k_{31} & k_{32} & k_{33} & k_{34}\\
    k_{41} & k_{42} & k_{43} & k_{44}\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

and a displacement vector u
$$
  u =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
    0 \\
    u_{2} \\
    u_{3} \\
    u_{4} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

The result for $F = Ku$ would be like this:

$$
  F =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
    F_{1} \\
    F_{2} \\
    F_{3} \\
    F_{4} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

What I don't understand: How is it possible that although $u_{1} = 0$ that $F_{1} \neq 0$. That means there is a force but no displacement? Does not every force cause a displacement? Can you explain this for me?

Comment: Funny title. +1.

Comment: When you step up to a weighing scales, the floor receives a force F=mg, but it does not move, hopefully for you. Such a force is called in mechanics "passive force" or "reactive constraint" because it does not exert any work. In nature, you can have either active or passive forces. When you work out the dynamic equilibrium of a mechanical system, the passive forces do not change the energetic content of the system, thus they do not affects the motion of the body, but usually they do affect the kinematics by removing some degrees of freedom.

Comment: @Gino Now I understand, thank you very much.

Comment: In the previous example, the passive force exerted by the floor prevents you from falling down, thus removing the possibility of moving downward (it removes the vertical motion). You can easily think and find out lots of examples of mechanical systems subjected to active and passive constraints, e.g. think about the door of your room...

Comment: This is a very clear explanation, thanks a lot.

Comment: I am happy I clarified!

Comment: Could F1 be Zero?